# how to use git checkout to checkout a specific commit from history of commits to another folder

Tags: git

consider that I have this in my git log:
commit 847a363f6676bf5d07c42d6ebec834fea1c9a363

-------------------Corrections:
Let me make corrections.
I use git as a back up and versioning tool. I want to get a previous version in my history of commits without affecting anything in my current working dir.
I just want a copy of all of my files in a given commit number in a separate dir.

Comment: This question makes no sense. The index is not a commit; it has no object ID. `git checkout-index` copies out of the index. Other commands copy out of commits (e.g., `git checkout` and `git reset`). Do you want to create a new temporary index, copy a commit to the temporary index, and then manipulate the temporary index, perhaps?

Comment: As @torek mentioned, specifying a commit with `git checkout-index` makes no sense, because the source of the files is the index, not a commit.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I made corrections to my question. thanks

Comment: Just make a clone of the repo (file system clone perhaps?) and then check out the commit you want

Comment: What’s the ultimate end-goal here? To work on a separate working tree of the repo simultaneously? To package up an old version to send it off? Something else?

Comment: to get the old version of the file

Comment: Use *git worktree add /new/copy commitID*

Answer (score 3):

```
mkdir -p /path/to/it
git archive 847a363f6676bf5d07c42d6ebec834fea1c9a363 | tar Cx /path/to/it
```

which also allows filtering on the way out, see the `export-ignore` and `export-subst` attributes.

Another method,

> without affecting anything in my current working dir. I just want a copy of all of my files in a given commit number in a separate dir

uses a throwaway deployment index, like so:

```
mkdir -p /path/to/dest
GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/junk GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/dest \
        git read-tree -u 847a363f6676bf5d07c42d6ebec834fea1c9a363
rm .git/junk
```

and if you do want to add a commit as a subtree of the already-checked-out commit

```
git read-tree -u --prefix=path/to/dest/ 847a363f6676bf5d07c42d6ebec834fea1c9a363
```

another possibility:

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [git worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree). 
Use `git worktree add` to checkout the commit in another directory.
That's quite easy to use but I let you read the doc to know how to exactly do it...

Comment: The downvote requires an explanation because that **IS** the right solution!